# what does this underlined sentence in below picture mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image]

what did the professor do for the student? I do not follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **put something on [reserve](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reserve)** is a library term meaning to reserve a book or magazine for somebody.

If the professor puts something on reserve for a student, it means that he or she instructs the librarian to reserve it for the student. The student can then ask the librarian for the publications that the professor reserved for the student.

Comment: A nit-pick. Items on reserve are usually done for a class as a whole, not for individual students. So you would ask for any items put on reverse by Professor A for Class B.